# Social Engine and Zend framework default.tpl customization

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm new to Social Engine and Zend frame work. I want to customize Header and footer of my application. My default.tpl contains bellow code.

```
</head>
<body id="global_page_<?php echo $request->getModuleName() . '-' . $request->getControllerName() . '-' . $request->getActionName() ?>">
<div id="global_header">
<?php echo $this->content('header') ?>
</div>
<div id='global_wrapper'>
<div id='global_content'>
<?php //echo $this->content('global-user', 'before') ?>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
<?php //echo $this->content('global-user', 'after') ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="global_footer">
<?php echo $this->content('footer') ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want load some widgets in footer section. Can any one suggest me how to customize `<?php echo $this->content('footer') ?>`. And where the footer file located in my application?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First add a script location to your view and then inside your layout file just use `render()` or `partial()` depending on your needs.

ie:

In your controller:

```
$this->view->addScriptPath('/partials'); // Put your custom files here
```

In your view:

```
$this->render('customview.phtml')
```

[See here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) for more info. Try to use `render()` instead of `partial()` as it's quicker

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. In the footer I want add menu and social network share links and Twitter tweets using java script. where i can see footer content source code. $this->content('footer')

Comment: Can you answer the question of where the footer file is located? I am also wondering about this, primarily because I want the location of the template called here `<?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>`

Answer (score 0):

**content('footer') ?>** in your code calls view Helper Content.php

Content Page calls LoadContent method which collects data from two tables in Social engine

engine4_core_pages table which has a value of 2 as page_id for footer.  Based on this page_id (2), engine4_core_content table will be queried, which has the list of widgets that are loaded.  For now, one widget is used to display footer in content table is

"core.menu-footer" widget.  This widget is loaded in footer area of the template (default.tpl).